# From an M/G/1-queue to the M/M/1-queue

Tags: queueing-theory

Suppose I have an $M/G/1$-queue $Q$. Then I have an embedded Markov chain $Q(D)$ and the following theorem:

> If $\rho=\lambda \mathbb{E}[S]<1$, then $Q(D)$ is ergodic with a unique stationary distribution $\pi$, having generating function:
>   $$G(s)=\sum_j \pi_j s^j=(1-\rho)(s-1) \frac{M_S(\lambda(s-1))}{s-M_S(\lambda(s-1))},$$
>   where $M_S$ is the moment generating function of the service time $S$.

Now I want to apply this theorem to an $M/M/1$-queue. So I know that the service times $S$ are exponential distributed with parameter $\mu$. Therefore the moment generating function of $S$ is:
$$M_S(t)=\frac{\mu}{\mu-t}.$$
Now I calculatded the $G(s)$ of the theorem and got:
$$G(s)=\frac{1-\rho}{1-s\rho}.$$
Since I know that an $M/M/1$-queue for $\rho<1$ has the geometric distribution:
$$\Pr(Q(t)=n) \rightarrow (1-\rho) \rho^n,$$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$ and $\pi$ is the unique stationary distribution.

But the moment generating function of a geometric random variable is given by:
$$G(t)=\frac{1-\rho}{1-\rho e^t}.$$
So it isn't exactly the same as $G(s)=\frac{1-\rho}{1-s\rho}$... Can somebody explain me how can I conclude from $G(s)=\frac{1-\rho}{1-s\rho}$ that the queue is gemetric distributed? I appreciate any help! Thank you!!

Comment: [PGF of a geometric distribution](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Probability_Generating_Function_of_Geometric_Distribution)

Comment: I just solved it by myself... Thank you anyway!